# Asp.Net 3.5 Listview WebserverControl dataitem showing null but it has value from SQL db. How to copy selected data from one listview to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

**My ListView Web Server Control :**

```
      <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataKeyNames="auth_Date">
```

**My Template**  :  (Only relevant portion is posting)

```
          <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="auth_DateTextBox" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("auth_Date") %>' />
          </td>
```

I want to take some selected data from this listview1 to another listview2 in a button click event..

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            DataRowView dataRow = ((DataRowView)item.DataItem);
        }

        var p = item.FindControl("auth_DateTextBox");
        Response.Write(p);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "auth_Date = '" + p+ "'";
        ListView2.DataSource = dv;
        ListView2.DataBind();


    }
}
```

But I am getting null in variable p. (it says cannot find column and dataitem is null) But i have used sql source to populate data. still it shows null...why ?

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as under:

```
        TextBox txtDate = (TextBox)item.FindControl("auth_DateTextBox");
        Response.Write(txtDate.Text);
        dv.RowFilter = "auth_Date = '" + txtDate.Text+ "'";
```